# Android: (De)Activating TapSpecs when a application successfully connected

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

This is my first application with Android! ;-)
I have got a TabHost with 4 TabSpecs. The "Account" is for the Connection (it should always work) the others should only work if the Login was successful and there is a connection to the service (which uses a RESTful API).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp5DT.png

I thought it would be helpful to have a Handler in the TabAcivitiy to change the TabSpecs-Status:

```
      Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
            case NOTIFY_DATASET_CHANGED:
                if(ServiceFactory.connected()){
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(true);
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(false);
                }   
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

The static function connected() tests the connection to the RESTful API.
But now I do not know how I should proceed because I don't know how to access this handler from a Activity (AccountActivity for example).

Any good ideas to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting an OnTabChangedListener for the TabHost. This callback will allow you to switch back to your login tab if they have not authenticated yet. Then after they've logged in you can allow them to change tabs.